# Is it possible to set a specific browser when using gatsby develop?

Tags: browser, gatsby

Windows 10 Pro x64
VS Code
Node 15.10.0

My default browser, for day-to-day work is Chrome, but when developing websites I've started using Firefox Developer. Is there a way to specify which browser I want Gatsby to open while I'm testing the site on my local machine?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify which browser I want Gatsby to open while
> I'm testing the site on my local machine?

No, you can't.

[According to `gatsby-cli` options](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/#options), the `-o` or `--open` flags opens the default browser at `localhost:8000` but you can't choose the browser, it will take the default system browser since it's a bash command, outside of Gatsby's scope.

You can make a PR to Gatsby's repository if you want with your proposal or you can dive into customizing the bash prompt, maybe this SuperUser answer enlights you: https://superuser.com/questions/350309/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-google-chrome-from-the-terminal-in-os-x